# Не меняется макет(layout) при повороте экрана

Tags: android

Чтобы избежать бага в конструкторе фрагмента добавлен метод: *setRetainInstance(true)*

При повороте экрана в *onCreateView* фрагмента я делаю:

`rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);`

Но вся верстка съезжает. Я предполагаю, что это вызванно тем что экран для портретного/горизонтального отображается на горизонтальном/портретном.

Как вызвать перерисовку экрана со сменой макета.

Для портретного

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="48"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_right_border">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/chanel_fragment_progress"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            <ExpandableListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/chanel_list"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:groupIndicator="@null"
                android:divider="#ffffff" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="52"
        android:background="@color/border_color">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/label_online_chanel"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/chanel_online_fragment"
                    android:tag="1">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/chanel_online_fragment"
                    android:id="@+id/chanel_guide_fragment"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_right_border">

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Для горизонталки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="48"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_right_border">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/chanel_fragment_progress"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            <ExpandableListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/chanel_list"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:groupIndicator="@null"
                android:divider="#ffffff" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="52"
        android:background="@color/border_color">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/label_online_chanel"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/chanel_online_fragment"
                    android:tag="1">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/chanel_online_fragment"
                    android:id="@+id/chanel_guide_fragment"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_right_border">

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

onCreateView фрагмента

```
Logi.d("CF onCreateView");
    try {
    //IApplication.getmInstanses().getTypeScreen() - тип устройства телефон или планшет
        if (IApplication.getmInstanses().getTypeScreen() != 1) {
            if (rootView == null) {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.fragment, container, false);
            }
        } else {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        Logi.e("Chanelfragment.OnCreateView: " + e);
    }
    return rootView;
```

Comment: Покажите верстку, используете ли вы правильные ресурсы для горизонатльного отображения layout-land?

Comment: Испортилось именно после этой строчки добавления. То есть за макеты я уверен.

Comment: покажите код, `onCreateVIew`, Где вы инфлейтите `layout`

Comment: Конструктор фрагмента всегда должен быть пустой, пользуйтесь методами жизненного цикла.

Answer (score 1):

layout для горизонтального режима положите в папку res/layout-land. При смене ориентации, если в манифесте у activity не стоит атрибут  android:configChanges="orientation", она будет создана по-новой и ваш fragment в ней тоже будет создан по-новой, а ресурсы для новой ориентации система подтянет автоматически из нужной папки

Comment: Все это у меня уже стоит.Вопрос решился, но я вроде бы на свой могу ответить только через два дня от создания. В общем, сумарные действия:   Ставим фрагменту, в онкреате чтобы он не пересоздавался.  В он креативьюв всегда перерисовываем лайоут. Для активити в манифесте ставим, как указано выше.